# Error while debugging a Xamarin iOS System.Net.HttpMessageHandler

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services, xamarin-studio

I am new on Xamarin...
I am trying to build a iOS application using Xamarin Studio on a mac, i am trying to use Azure  Mobile Services too, but i get the following Error:

The type System.Net.HttpMessageHandler is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a (CS0012)

on the following code:

```
public static MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("URL","Key");
```

Somebody knows whats going on???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding the HttpClient PCL Nuget package as well as the BCL.Async PCL package to your project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same issue while working on a cross platform app.  I simply added a reference to System.Net.Http in my android project and this resolved the problem.  I'm assuming the same might work for your IOS project as well.

Comment: Simply adding the reference to System.Net.Http worked for me.